# The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed

Tags: composer-php

```
When I run the following command
```

> sudo composer update

```
then I am getting following error.
```

> The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be
>   downloaded: SSL operation failed      with code 1. OpenSSL Error
>   messages:
>   error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
>   Failed to enable crypto
>   failed to open stream: operation failed

Answer (score 5):

I came across this issue on OSX after using Homebrew to upgrade to PHP 7.0.12.

To resolve the problem I downloaded `cacert.pem` using WGET.

`wget http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem`

I saved that file to my home directory `/Users/alex/cacert.pem`. Then configured my PHP.ini file to point to that cacert location.

To do this; First locate your `php.ini` and run the command `php --ini` that should produce:

```
$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/7.0
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/conf.d
```

The INI file to edit is the one at the Loaded Configuration File location. Open that file in your editor of choice (Vim, etc) and find the setting `openssl.cafile`. This is probably commented out so uncomment it and insert the location of your `cacert.pem`.

You should then be able to run `compose install`, `composer update`, `composer self-update`, etc

Comment: Why is this certificate required?

Answer (score 1):

You need to reboot your computer.

I had it on virtual environment Vagrant Laravel Homestead.

To fix id I did

```
vagrant halt
...
vagrant up
```

Answer (score 0):

> Certain Composer commands, including exec, install, and update allow
>   third party code to execute on your system. This is from its "plugins"
>   and "scripts" features. Plugins and scripts have full access to the
>   user account which runs Composer. For this reason, it is strongly
>   advised to avoid running Composer as super-user/root.
>
> You can disable plugins and scripts during package installation or
>   updates with the following syntax so only Composer's code, and no
>   third party code, will execute:

```
composer install --no-plugins --no-scripts
composer update --no-plugins --no-scripts
```

The exec command will always run third party code as the user which runs composer.

> In some cases, like in CI systems or such where you want to install
>   untrusted dependencies, the safest way to do it is to run the above
>   command.

```
so always run composer without sudo
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried these solutions, but none of them worked for me. I know it may sounds like a dummy workaround, but this what I did in case anyone find it useful:

1) temporarily I enabled my mobile as a wifi hotspot.
2) connected my laptop to this wifi. I have my Vagrant VM here, with Laravel/Composer running.
3) I disabled all proxy environment settings (e.g. http_proxy, https_proxy, etc) within my VM.
4) Then, I successfully created my project, by using "composer global require "laravel/installer" and "composer create-project laravel/laravel" commands.
5) disconnected the wifi hotspot, and started to work normally (ethernet).

HTH.
Carlos.

Answer (score 0):

I met this issue on Virtualbox - Ubuntu / Docker / PHP7 and fix by restarting the Ubuntu.