# PHP Composer failed to open stream: Cannot connect to HTTPS server through proxy

Tags: php, composer-php

While running composer install, I keep getting following error all of a sudden

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
 The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL
  operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
 error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
failed to open stream: Cannot connect to HTTPS server through proxy
```

Does anyone had this issue before?

Following are my composer settings -

```
[cache-ttl] 15552000
[cache-files-ttl] 15552000
[cache-files-maxsize] 300MiB (314572800)
[bin-compat] auto
[discard-changes] false
[autoloader-suffix]
[sort-packages] false
[optimize-autoloader] false
[classmap-authoritative] false
[apcu-autoloader] false
[prepend-autoloader] true
[github-domains] [github.com]
[bitbucket-expose-hostname] true
[disable-tls] true
[secure-http] false
[cafile]
[capath]
[github-expose-hostname] true
[gitlab-domains] [gitlab.com]
[store-auths] prompt
[archive-format] tar
[archive-dir] .
[htaccess-protect] 1
```

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/40594780/1852444

Comment: it has to do with your server configuration. See this issue https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5411 might have some insight on what settings you might have to change.

Answer (score 2):

The problem resolved for me by making this:

```
HTTP_PROXY_REQUEST_FULLURI=false
```

It is a Composer environment parameter, there is one for the HTTP and the HTTPS proxy:

> **HTTP_PROXY_REQUEST_FULLURI**
>
> If you use a proxy, but it does not support the request_fulluri flag, then you should set this env var to `false` or `0` to prevent Composer from setting the request_fulluri option.
>
> **HTTPS_PROXY_REQUEST_FULLURI**
>
> If you use a proxy, but it does not support the request_fulluri flag for HTTPS requests, then you should set this env var to false or 0 to prevent Composer from setting the request_fulluri option. *([source](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#http-proxy-request-fulluri))*

Both relating to the ***request_fulluri** flag*:

> **`request_fulluri`** bool
>
> When set to **`true`**, the entire URI will be used when constructing the request. (e.g. `GET http://www.example.com/path/to/file.html HTTP/1.0`). While this is a non-standard request format, some proxy servers require it. *([source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php#context.http.request-fulluri))*

Answer (score -1):

Composer uses wget to request the network.

```
:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
failed to open stream: Cannot connect to HTTPS server through a proxy
```

I think you can add `check_certificate = off` in your `~/.wgetrc` not to check certificates. If you prefer you can configure certificate verification in `/etc/wgetrc` too.

Comment: Can you share more details about this? The whole repository for Composer doesn't contain a single call of wget

Comment: Composer is a PHP Script that uses an HTTP client installed on the computer. Often this type of issue is caused by the HTTP client configuration.

On my linux, I have curl and wget installed and it's the wget configuration used that is why configuring wget can help.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. I cannot see any reference that Composer uses the HTTP client of your computer. It rather uses cURL or file_get_contents. Do you have any information about Composer using wget?